# Is there any way to capture the object/property on which object reference not set to an instance of an object error is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, nullreferenceexception

I am working on an existing project, which have thousands of object and properties.

Is there any way to capture the exact object/property name by which object reference not set to an instance of an object error is thrown?

Comment: on an ad-hoc basis? the stack trace will usually get you most of the way there; more generally, consider a: adding NRT support and *dealing appropriately with any compiler warnings*, and b: adding validation in your code - for example `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(someArg);` or `Debug.Assert(someArg is not null);` (the latter only applies to code compiled in debug mode)